# What are the Hosts and the Records in my Domains DNS?

Tags: web-hosting, dns

I am struggling with the details of my domains DNS details.
While I found some information on the different types of records (A, CNAME and MX)
on Wikipedia and in Stackoverflow, I don't know what the different Hosts like * and @ mean.
In my case for example, the top two lines with @ and * point to the same IP.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` record signifies what your domain name itself resolves to. So if your domain is `example.com`, that record controls what `example.com` (with nothing in front of it) resolves to.

The `*` record is a *wildcard* record. If present, these control what any hostname not covered by another record would resolve to. E.g. `foo.example.com`, `abc123fsjfkslfs.example.com` and so on. You don't have to have a wildcard DNS record - if this wasn't there, these hostnames wouldn't resolve to anything.

It is common for both of these records to point to the same IP, which in your case will be the IP address of your web server. Assuming your screenshot covers all of the DNS records for your domain, the first is what allows http://example.com/ to work, and the second will allow http://www.example.com/ to work (since you don't have a separate `www` A record).